Most reliable method for normalisation and popularity handling in item-item co-occurance?
In section 19.4 of https://animlbook.com/recommender_systems/recommendation/index.html co-occurance matrix is suggested and Jaccard similarity is one of the normalisation methods suggested.
Other common method of normalisation are PMI or NPMI (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise_mutual_information). Few other people suggest row normalisation.
Request to please suggest:

Methods for normalising the co-occurances
Handling global popularity bias.

PS: The item feature in my case is highly cardinal.
